# Zooming in Cartopy orthographic plots

Tags: matplotlib, orthographic, cartopy

I'm trying to zoom in some Cartopy plots in Orthographic projection, but it seems it is not possible with the simple `ax.set_extent()` method.
The code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.Orthographic())
ax.set_global()
ax.set_extent((-120,120,50,90), crs = ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I receive the following error: 
 `ValueError: Failed to determine the required bounds in projection coordinates.`

Actually I'd only need to set a lower boundary latitude to make a plot of the polar region, which I used to do before with Basemap. However I do not see how to proceed with Cartopy.

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your longitude extent is too big, in that neither -120 or 120 are on the orthographic disk with central longitude/latitude of 0 (they are "behind" it). You could first query what the global longitude extent is then use that instead of (-120, 120).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.Orthographic())
ax.set_global()

global_extent = ax.get_extent(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent(global_extent[:2] + (50, 90), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
```

[image: Orthographic projection with limited extent]

Comment: ok, thank you, that was indeed the problem. Actually I was looking for a way to set just a lower boundary latitude, but it's only possible to set a square box if I understand. The (-120,120) was probably confusing, sorry for that..

Answer (score 0):

I do have slight problems imagining how the desired Orthograhic projection with the restricted coordinates is desired to look like - and supposedly cartopy has similar issues of understanding :-).
But of course you can use a different (and potentially more suitable) projection; `LambertConformal` may make sense.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-96.0, central_latitude=39.0, )
ax = plt.axes(projection = proj)

ax.set_extent((-120,120,50,90), crs = ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.gridlines()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The (-120,120) was probably confusing, sorry for that.. Actually I was just looking for a way to set a lower boundary latitude in an Orthographic projection. (similar to the "boundinglat" option available in basemap)